# Simple SQL statement with parent/child hierarchies

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's been a while since I've needed to write SQL statements (and I don't even know if ever had enough knowledge to make this statement).

So, here's the deal. Table has two column. One is for parent id, other is for child Id.

```
parent_id | child_id
        4 |        2
        2 |        5
```

This is simply for saving composite parent/child hierarchies.

4, 2 line means that structure with id 4 refers to structure id 2 as a child.
2, 5 means structure with id 2 refers to structure with id 5 as a child.
And so on.

This is what I need to do:
I need to extract ALL structures, that are not referenced by any structure as a child (root structures).
What SQL (preferrably postgres) statement will accomplish that?

Comment: [Joe Celko's SQL Hierarchies for Smarties](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334)

Comment: Well, that's alright, but I don't think I'll write that many SQL statements in my life to read the entire book...

Comment: Try joining the table to itself on child_id = parent_id and doing an outer join

Comment: Ok, dont bother learning then, just have SO solve all your problems, that will make you very valuable to your employer.

Comment: Look man, I work with C++ most of my time calculating vectors and fixing insane bugs within 100,000s lines of code, and this is what I need to do for my university project so I would get a good grade. Don't worry, I'm valuable to my employers enough as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding all structures that are not a child of another structure:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   Parent_Id not in (Select child_id from ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no scope for a **grandparent, great-grandparent** relationsips, I would recommend use a `Left-JOIN` in this case.

Somethink on the lines of:

```
Select * from Table
LEFt join Table on Parent_id=child_id
WHERE  child_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT *
   FROM structures
   WHERE id not in ( SELECT child_id FROM Table ) AS dummy
```